# Некорректно считывается информация из файла .BMP

Tags: c++, c, bmp

Заранее извиняюсь за код.

Нужно вывести hex-значения цветов пикселей .bmp файла. Размер файла 10х10 пикселей. Вот основной код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fheader.height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < fheader.width; j++) {
        int padding = fheader.pixels_adress + i * 4 * fheader.width + 4 * j;
        file.seekg(padding, ios::beg);
        file.read((char*)&fheader.test, sizeof(int));
        cout << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << fheader.test << dec << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

В fheader хранится информация о файле. Т.е. размер, адрес начала растр. данных и тд.

При запуске все работает отлично до момента, когда padding > 438 — последние 4 байта файла считываются не корректно (все одинаковые).

[image]
При этом, напрямую выводит нормально.

```
file.seekg(438, ios::beg);
file.read((char*)&fheader.test, sizeof(int));
cout << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << fheader.test << dec << " ";
file.seekg(442, ios::beg);
file.read((char*)&fheader.test, sizeof(int));
cout << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << fheader.test << dec << " ";
file.seekg(446, ios::beg);
file.read((char*)&fheader.test, sizeof(int));
cout << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << fheader.test << dec << " ";
file.seekg(450, ios::beg);
file.read((char*)&fheader.test, sizeof(int));
cout << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << fheader.test << dec << " ";
```

[image]

Comment: Используя функции в/в типа seekg(), read() и т.д. надо ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО проверять состояние ошибки. А Вы этого не делаете. Вот и непонятно - что происходит. Скорее всего - последний вызов read() завершается ошибкой.

Comment: Зачем в 3 строке формула с кучей умножений? Мне кажется, что в ней дело.

Comment: @Sergey, сделал проверку. Да, последние 5 вызовов read() вызывают ошибку. В этих случаях file.tellg() возвразает -1, хотя позиция на которую сдвигаем равна 438, 442, 446, 450 соответственно. 
Если же убрать ф-цию read(), все нормально (seekg работает корректно).
https://i.imgur.com/zLfkztf.png

Comment: А ваш bmp 32-х или 24-х битный? Обычно они 24-х битные, т.е. по 3 байта на пиксель + выравнивание в конце каждой строки. Другими словами, смещение рассчитывается совсем по другой формуле нежели у вас.

Comment: @zed этот 32-х битный

Comment: @supermishboy В голову приходит два варианта: 1) Размер файла не 456, а меньше. 2) *padding* принимает значения восе не 438, 442, 446, 450 а большие. Чудес не бывает!